# How to merge more than two tables and have matched and unmatched records from all the tables in the result set

Tags: sql

I have to join more than two tables and the result set should contain all the unmatched and matched (without duplicates).

Please find the example below. I know how to merge two tables for this scenario but need help to merge more than two (almost 20 tables). Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please share all details (like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output) in text form

Comment: Very weird table design. Why is city and grade in one table, and salary and street in another table.

Comment: @jarlh -- this is just a sample table please ignore the columns or the values. I have two columns in my real tables like EId and Ename in my example here

Comment: @NicoHaase -- This what I have tried so far, I'm able to get the expected result with two tables, but I have to merge more than two tables.                                               --------------  select ft.eid, ft.ename, ft.edepartment, st.ecity, st.egrade from employee1 ft left join employee2 st on ft.eid = st.eid and ft.ename = st.ename
union
select st.eid, st.ename, ft.edepartment, st.ecity, st.egrade from employee1 ft right join employee2 on ft.eid = st.eid and ft.ename = st.ename

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important stuff

Comment: @NicoHaase -- I don't understand what clarification you're expecting to add to my question

Comment: Add the table structure, sample input data, and your attempts **in text form**